# Checking for null value in HttpContext.Current Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpcontext

We have strange situation where something is causing an exception on `Http.Current` object such as `.Response` or `.Request`. The exception is NullReferecne. I was under the impression that HTTPContext under normal circumstances can't be null. But since in our case it can how should I handle this type of exception? We're already handle HTTPException in Global.asax.cs and with ErrorSeverity as Fatal which is home grown class. I 've modified the code that checks for null value but I'm not cetain if that really catches this scenario - see code below:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
            HttpException httpException = exception as HttpException;
            if (httpException != null)
            {
                if (httpException.GetHttpCode() == 404)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
            string errMessage = "Running Application_Error. An unhandled error occured in the application.";
            errMessage = errMessage + "Error message = " + exception.Message;

            //This is the IF-ELSE I've added but it just doesn't "feel right"
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request != null || HttpContext.Current.Response != null)
            {
                StaticServices.ErrorLogger.LogSingleException(exception, ErrorSeverity.Fatal);
            }
            else
            {
                StaticServices.ErrorLogger.LogSingleException(exception, ErrorSeverity.Info);
            }

            exception = exception.InnerException;
            while (exception != null)
            {
                StaticServices.ErrorLogger.LogSingleException(exception, ErrorSeverity.Fatal);
                exception = exception.InnerException;
            }

            QSession session = QSession.GetInstance();
            bool mobileIndicator = session != null ? session.Packet.QPolicy.IsMobileApplication : false; 
            if (mobileIndicator)
            {
                    LogAndRedirectTechDiff("MobileTechnicalDifficulties.htm", session != null);
            }
            else
            {
                //This is the IF-ELSE I've added but it just doesn't "feel right"                   
                if (HttpContext.Current.Request != null || HttpContext.Current.Response != null)
                {
                    LogAndRedirectTechDiff("TechnicalDifficulties.htm", session != null);
                }
                else
                {
                    LogAndRedirectTechDiff("UnsupportedBrowser.htm", session != null);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry("FQ",
                                "Global.asax.cs Application_Error method caused an exception. This is the error message :" +
                                ex.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Haven't you [already asked this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22077119/will-the-httpcontext-have-null-value-when-unsupported-browser)?

Comment: In a different context, yes. This one is more to the point. Deleted the other one.